# Getting CORS Error when sending REST-Call from Angular to Camunda Rest-Engine

Tags: angular, rest, tomcat, cors, camunda

I am quite new to Camunda and I wanted to write a small Angular program that controls a deployed BPMN process using the REST engine.

So far so good, so I downloaded the Open Source Community Platform from the official Camunda site `https://camunda.com/de/download/`. I was also able to start everything via start-camunda.bat and TomCat initialized on `localhost:8080`. My process is also deployed and I am able to place REST calls via Postman to control the process and get information.

So REST calls via Postman works!

Now to my problem. My Angular App runs over `ng serve` on `localhost:4200` and of course there are CORS problems when I send the GET-Request `http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-definition` from the App.

```js
this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-definition')
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

After some internet research I found 2 solutions. Either you set up a proxy in the Angular App:

---

### Solution 1 - Proxy

**src/proxy.conf.json**

```
{
  "/engine-rest": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080"
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angularTest:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"  <-- Add this line
          },...
```

If I then execute a `ng serve` it will tell me `[HPM] Proxy created: /engine-rest -> http://localhost:8080` but when I send the Rest Call it still gets me the following CORS Error.

[image: CORS-Error]

[image]

---

### Solution 2 - TomCat web.xml

The second solution I tried was to add a filter to the top of the `web.xml` under `server\apache-tomcat-9.0.33\webapps\engine-rest\WEB-INF\web.xml` and restart the server.

**Filter**

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

---

So both of those **solutions** should fix that CORS Error, but in my case they don't and I can't explain how and why. So maybe it's just super simple and i'm just stupid

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in proxy file

```js
//Change
{
  "/engine-rest": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080"
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}

//TO
{
  "/engine-rest": {
      "target": "https://camunda.com/"
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to work. Still getting the same CORS Error. But i found out that if I run Chrome with runtime Arguments `--disable-web-security` the calls are not blocked by CORS anymore.
So it seems that only the Browser is responsible for the CORS Error.
But I am still confused why Proxy does not work properly...

Comment: CORS is meant to be handled from the browser anyway due to the HTTP requests involved. That said, any updates to getting this solved? @CrazyEight

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic error on rest calls from a different front to back end. When you call an api from a front end (Angular, React, anything) that is in a back end (Tomcat, Jetty, Python, PHP, Node, anything), you need to specify in your back end a cors filter that allows specifically the url from your front end.
After this, look at this piece of code on how to enable this in Tomcat:

```
 <filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Note the tag with this: "cors.allowed.origins", put in the respective tag below it your front end address: "http://localhost:4200" (without ").